# Alter htaccess for $_GET utm_medium from dlvr.it

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

Dlvr.it puts utm_source and utm_medium in the URLs it generates. I am trying to access those in my PHP code but the page cannot get its value. The two values of utm_medium I'm looking to track are twitter or Facebook.

Example url that doesn't work: example.com/page/id?utm_source=dlvrit&utm_medium=twitter
Example that DOES work: example.com/page.php?id=xxx&utm_medium=twitter

Any one have any idea why I cannot access it or any experience with using dlvr.it generated URLs?

What I have:

```
$source = $_GET['utm_medium'];
echo $source;
```

I am getting the error: Undefined index: utm_medium

EDIT: My htaccess is structured so the page is displayed as /page/xxx (xxx being an id number) so the parameters from dlvr.it are not active. How can I go about altering my htaccess to gain access to these parameters?

Comment: What is the result of `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin Array ( [id] => 117 ) is the output

Comment: The only thing I could tell is that the page which is called is `yourwebsite.com/page.php?id=117`. There is no `utm_medium` variable. Is it possible that you should recieve it in a `POST`? so trying `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin As I have edit in my question above, it has to do with my .htaccess file. the page is page.php?id=xxx but I have it set up to be /page/xxx. So I guess the extra url parameters are not working. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Add the flag `[QSA]` to your RewriteRule – stands for Query String Append, and will append the original query string to the address that you rewrite to internally.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much! Mind putting that as an answer so I can credit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the flag `[QSA]` to your RewriteRule – stands for Query String Append, and will append the original query string to the address that you rewrite to internally.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa:

> *“When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.”*